# Get mysqli commit 2 pages further

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

So I have a form of stuff people have to fill in and if the email they type in doesn't exist you get a register page, and I save the stuff they filled in in a mysqli query and I want to commit it if the registration process is complete. But to check this I need to take the query to the next page.

Long story short I need to carry the query to the next page when they press submit.

It can also be the $_POST values but I think saving all those values in a session would be ugly coding. So whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: Thats _exactly_ what sessions are for, why would this be ugly coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to post the actual query to the next page, since information about your table(s) will be visible by all. A good way to go about it is to just store all the info in a session from every form like normal (it's okay if it's several different values, it's definitely not a bad coding practice), grab them on the next page, and create/execute your query there. That way, the information sent over is the stuff the user had already typed in, and all of your database calls remain invisible. Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay so I should just put all the values of the previous page in a session and destroy those afterwards?

Comment: Yup, that definitely works! You can also send them over with POST or GET, depending on the sensitivity of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use sessions now and to keep my code clean I made use of an array and a foreach.
Just wanted to share this.

```
$posts = array("value1","value2");
foreach ($posts as $post) {
   if (isset($_POST[$post])) {
      $_SESSION[$post] = $_POST[$post];
      $$post = $_SESSION[$post];
   }
}
```